# data cannot pass to another page after submitted

Tags: php, forms

I wanted to pass the form data to another page after validate.
The user have to enter the correct data in order to proceed to next page.
I was trying to get the data from the first page but seems like it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset ="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>
Register
</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$firstNameErr = $surNameErr ="";
$firstName = $surName = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

     $valid = true;

  if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
    $firstNameErr = "FirstName is required";
    $valid = false;
  } else {
    $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
      $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }

  }

  if (empty($_POST["surName"])) {
    $surNameErr = "surName is required";
    $valid = false;
  } else {
    $surName = test_input($_POST["surName"]);
    // check if name only contain letters and whitespace 
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
      $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }


  if($valid){
   header('Location: successReg.php');
   exit();
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  

  FirstName <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstNameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>

  SurName <input type="text" name="surName" value="<?php echo $surName;?>">
  <span class="error">*<?php echo $surNameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>



  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above shows the registration form.
After the "submit" button is pressed, it send to successReg.php

Here is the successReg.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<title> Register successfully</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    /* Get each parameter value from the request stream and using ternary if operators check each parameter to see if it was set. If it is, store it in a variable.  */

    $firstName  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'firstName');
    $surName    = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'surName'  );


    $firstName   = filter_var($firstName , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES ); 
    $firstName  = filter_var($firstName,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $surName    = filter_var($surName , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES );
    $surName    = filter_var($surName,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);


    echo" $firstName";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the last line of the successReg.php page, I'm trying get the data from the submitted page to see whether the data can be retrieved or not.
And also, the successReg.php page is supposed to insert all the data into the database.
The `echo $firstName` is for testing purpose, but seems it doesn't work.
If the data is successfully passed from the form page, I will only continue with the sql code.

Is there any mistake, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the user to the success page without it knowing which values to show. You could do this a few ways.

When you send them to the new page, you could amend the latest database insert id and then pick up the result on the success page (not than you have that active yet), or

You could just pass the values directly as a GET and display them on the success page.

Such as:

```
 if($valid){
     echo '<a href="successReg.php?firstName=' . $firstName . '&surName=' .  $surName . '">Continue on</a>'; 
   exit();
  }
```

Comment: is there any way to pass the data to successReg.php directly after all the validation is true and redirected??

Comment: @ccs how did you go?